# How to take no more than a constant?

Tags: f#

Im trying to learn F#.

I want to take no more elements from Seq (or array) than a constant.

I use this code: `[ "11"; "12"; "13" ] |> Seq.take 2 |> Seq.toList |> Seq.iter (printf "%A ")` I get `"11" "12"`

If I try `[ "11"; "12"; "13" ] |> Seq.take 4 |> Seq.toList |> Seq.iter (printf "%A ")` I get an exception like `System.InvalidOperationException: The input sequence has an insufficient number of elements.`

I can think of takeWhile as in `[ "11"; "12"; "13" ] |> Seq.takeWhile (fun elem -> true) |> Seq.toList |> Seq.iter (printf "%A ")`
But I have no idea how to stop taking on reaching some constant limit.

So I need something like `[ "11"; "12"; "13" ] |> Seq.takeNoMoreThan 4 |> Seq.toList |> Seq.iter (printf "%A ")`.

I have no idea how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [Seq.truncate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370325.aspx) instead.